# How can I create a dynamic array with different random values in random size?

Tags: system-verilog

Interview question:
I have a systemverilog based class as following:

```
class A;
rand n;
constraint c:{n>=10 &&n<=15};
bit [31:0] arr[];
randc [31:0] data;
endclass
```

In this case 'n' is the size of the dynamic array arr. And the question is how to write a method to create the array so that all the elements in this array is different from each other.

So the problem is randc type can only make sure each time I instantiate the class, I get a different value, but how can I store those value in an array like this? Any help is appreciated.

P.S. There may be mistakes in the class and it is editable.

Comment: The **unique** constraint, which was added in IEEE 1800-2012 makes this question trivial. The interview question should be modified to ask how to do it without the unique constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the **unique** constraint.

```
class A;
  rand bit [31:0] arr[];

  constraint arr_size { arr.size() inside {[10:15]}; }
  constraint arr_uniq { unique {arr}; }

endclass
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `rand` before `bit [31:0] arr[]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The interviewer didn't want me to use unique, so how to do that without the unique constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Without unique, you can do something like this :

```
class T;
  randc bit [31:0] x;
endclass

class A;
  rand bit [31:0] arr[];
  local T temp;

  function void post_randomize();
    foreach (arr[i])
    begin
      void'(temp.randomize());
      arr[i] = temp.x;
    end 
    void'(temp.randomize());  
  endfunction

  constraint size_con { arr.size() inside {[10:15]}; }
endclass
```

Comment: Is it the same when implementing this in post_rand and pre_rand? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: I believe, only 2 methods are there : pre_randomize & post_randomize, not pre_rand, post_rand

Comment: Sry, typo. I wanna ask difference between pre_randomize & post_randomize.

Comment: pre_randomize is the method, to automatically gets executed, just before randomization of the class. Similarly, post_randomize will be executed, just after randomization of the class

Comment: If this is what you want, then you can mark it as answer.

Comment: for what purpose the last "void'(temp.randomize()); " is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique random pattern of a dynamic array with just using some tight constraint.I try to give some solution for the same.I have also add one code example for the same. hope it will help you.

```
class A;

  rand int a[];

  constraint generate_unique_dyn_array {
  foreach( a[ii] )
   {
       foreach( a[jj] )
       {
            if( ii != jj )
                 a[ii] != a[jj] ;
       }
   }
}
endclass
```

Comment: This brute-force solution creates too many individual constraints, which could slow down simulation as the size of the array is growing bigger.